# Getting aapt source using git

Tags: android, aapt

how can I download Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) source using git from this URL https://android.googlesource.com/?

Thanks

Comment: they wriitten on top `To clone one of these repositories, install git, and run:
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/name`

Comment: I would like to download the source for the aapt tool. But I don't know which git URL to use.

Comment: I think aapt tool is under this https://android.googlesource.com/Kernel-Projects repo. So you need to clone whole source.

Comment: It is under [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

aapt is located in the Google repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.

Can be cloned by running: `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base`

Answer (score -1):

get GITbash from the below link --> run the command window utility --> copy paste the command line from the repository.

[Git Bash](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)

You can either use the command line or the GIT gui tool too.